# What's the last GTA V Franklin mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

The only character with a number below their name is Franklin, this indicates that there is a mission remaining, but I cannot find it! Any ideas what it might be? Could it be a street race, as I have not done all of those?

Comment: Could you say at which mission you are at? I'm currently on a mission without a marker, because I need to find 4 cars in locations I only know from 4 pictures that Lester sent me. Go in the in-game menu and click on "Brief", you may find a hint there. :) Good luck

Comment: Missions: 69/69
Hobbies & Passtimes: 27/42
Strangers & Freaks: 15/20
Random Events: 11/14
Misc: 3/16
I think it might be the UFO parts mission, actually. On the other hand, Michael still has the submarine parts mission unfinished, and that doesn't show up on the switcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last mission for Franklin is a Strangers and Freaks mission, which can only be done after a 100% completion in the game. The Strangers and Freaks mission can only be performed by Franklin.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for a while also.  Call Tonya, she wants you to tow for Jb who is to busy smoking to do his job.

Comment: This one! Franklin had an "extra" mission for the first 20 hours that I couldn't see on the map. Finally tried ringing contacts on the phone to see if any of them had jobs, and bingo!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of missions that can be considered as the last one for Franklin:

- [Something Sensible](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Something_Sensible), [The Time's Come](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Time%27s_Come) or [The Third Way](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Third_Way)

  - The game ending (you can only pick one, and The Third Way is confirmed to be the canon option)
- [The Last One](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_One)

  - Strangers and Freaks mission after completing the 100%